# Symfony | Redirections with Firefox doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, firefox, redirect

I have been developing a project with Symfony 2.8 and I've got a problem with redirections on Firefox. It works fine on every other browser but not in Firefox. When you click on the button on this page it won't redirect to any page in Firefox.

My code in a twig:

```
<button class="MoreButton" type="button">
    <a href="{{ path('poznan') }}">Więcej</a>
</button>
```

My code in a controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/poznan", name="poznan")
 */
public function poznanPage(Request $request)
{
    return $this->render('default/poznan.html.twig', []);
}
```

Do you have any ideas what might be wrong? :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :) It works after the button has been deleted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you put your link in a `button` element.

it doesn't make sens, it s a button or a link but not both. firefox is not able to catch the link inside the button. remove the button and it will work

Comment: Thanks a lot for help :) It works after the button has been deleted :)